# gpio value zero turns the circuit on why?

Tags: gpio

My Pi is acting in a way i'm not expecting.  When I set the value of a pin to 0 like

'echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value'
or when using python
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)

it has the effect of turning on the LED I have wired up.  Also when I set the value to 1 it turns the LED off.

Is my Pi broken or am I missing something?

Comment: How is the LED connected?

Comment: it is connected to the 3.3v power with a 270 ohm resistor followed by the LED then a connection back to GPIO18 pin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's correct behaviour, if your LED is connected to the +5V rail with a resistor:

```
GPIO resistor LED     +5V
   o---////---|<|-----x
```

you may try to connect it to the GND (ground) if you like to reverse the ON/OFF depending on the value you set to a GPIO pin.

Comment: So if I understand correctly by setting the pin to zero it has the effect of being a grounding pin and completing the circuit, is that the case?

Comment: @Robert : you're correct.